# How to comment a markdown tag

Tags: markdown

I have a markdown code
`![image name](https://i.ibb.co/yPGZBvY/1.png)`.
I want to comment it. Is it possible to do by
`<!-- ![image name](https://i.ibb.co/yPGZBvY/1.png) -->`

Comment: yes it is.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the image won't be displayed with `<!-- -->`.
 You can also use `[comment]: # (Your comment)`